# WSA UDP socket can't be reused as it forcibly closes the connection

Tags: c++, winsock

I need to close and then reuse the same socket in my app. The first time the socket connects it's able to connect properly, but a second time it's tried to be used, client gets a wsaerror 10054 (existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) from the server, and I see that server does not receive the "syn" data from the client. What seems to be wrong here? The client that has connected before is able to connect to a server again, but a server that has received a connection before is unable to accept a new connection as it somehow causes a 10054.

connectionmanager.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH 64

class ConnectionManager {
    private:
        fd_set fdset;
        struct timeval client_wait_timeout;
        struct timeval server_wait_timeout;

        SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

        // This is where we'll be setting up connection parameters or where we'll be storing the parameters for a connection that's made.
        SOCKADDR_IN connection_data;
        int connection_data_len = sizeof(connection_data);

        char receive_buffer[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH] = { 0 }; // The object where the recieved data will be placed on.
    public:
        std::wstring server_ipv4;

        bool is_connected = false;
        std::string type = "none";

        ConnectionManager();
        void init(std::string connection_type);
        void reset();
        bool establish_first_connection();
        bool await_first_connection();
        std::string receive_data();
        std::string send_data(std::string data);
};
```

connectionmanager.cpp

```
#include "connection_manager.hpp"

ConnectionManager::ConnectionManager() {
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int result;

    // Initialize Windows Sockets library, version 2.2.
    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata);

    if (result != 0)
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed, error: " << result << "\n";

    connection_data.sin_family = AF_INET; // Using IPv4
    connection_data.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);
}

void ConnectionManager::init(std::string connection_type) {
    int result = 0;

    if (connection_type == "server") {
        connection_data.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Bind the socket to all available interfaces - or in other words, accept connections from any IPv4 address. We'll change this after we establish our first connection with the client.

        // Create a socket for the server to listen from client for data / send data to client.
        sock = socket(connection_data.sin_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cerr << "Error occured while creating server socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            WSACleanup();
        }

        // Bind the listening socket.
        result = bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, connection_data_len);
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "Listening socket bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
        }

        std::cout << "Awaiting connection..." << "\n";
        if (!await_first_connection())
            std::cerr << "Either no one connnected during the 60 second period, or there was a problem with the server. Last WSA error:" << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Connected successfully!" << "\n";
            is_connected = true;
        }
    }
    else if (connection_type == "client") {
        InetPton(connection_data.sin_family, (PCWSTR)(server_ipv4.c_str()), &connection_data.sin_addr.s_addr); // Set the IP address to connect to on the connection_data structure.

        // Create a socket for sending data to server.
        sock = socket(connection_data.sin_family, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cerr << "Error occured while creating client socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            WSACleanup();
        }

        std::wcout << "Attempting to connect to " << server_ipv4 << "..." << "\n";
        if (!establish_first_connection())
            std::cerr << "There was a problem connecting the server. Last WSA error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        else {
            std::wcout << "Successfully connected to " << server_ipv4 << "!" << "\n";
            is_connected = true;
        }
    }

    // Put the socket in non-blocking mode.
    unsigned long mode = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, (unsigned long*)&mode) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Error while putting the socket into non-blocking mode: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    }
}

void ConnectionManager::reset() {
    is_connected = false;
    closesocket(sock);
}

/*
Functions "establish_first_connection" and "await_first_connection" do something that's quite similar to the three-way handshake method of a TCP connection.
*/

bool ConnectionManager::establish_first_connection() { // This will be used by the client.
    // Set up the file descriptor set.
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);
    
    int send_result = INT32_MAX;
    std::string syn_message = "SYN";

    send_result = sendto(sock, syn_message.c_str(), syn_message.length(), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, connection_data_len);
    if (send_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Error occured while attempting to send SYN to server: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    else {
        int result = 0;
        int receive_result = 0;

        // Set up the timeval struct for the timeout.
        // We'll wait for 10 seconds for the server to respond, or else we'll call the connection off.
        client_wait_timeout.tv_sec = 10; // seconds
        client_wait_timeout.tv_usec = 0; // microseconds

        // Wait until the timeout or until we receive data.
        result = select(sock, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &client_wait_timeout);
        if (result == 0)
            std::cout << "Timeout." << "\n"; // todo
        else if (result == -1)
            std::cerr << "Error occured while awaiting first connection data from server. Last WSA error:" << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

        receive_result = recvfrom(sock, receive_buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, &connection_data_len);
        if (receive_result > 0) { // If we received any data before the timeout, return true.
            std::string client_ack_message = "ACK";
            std::cout << receive_buffer << "\n";
            sendto(sock, client_ack_message.c_str(), client_ack_message.length(), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, connection_data_len);

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool ConnectionManager::await_first_connection() { // This will be used by the server.
    int result = 0;
    int receive_result = 0;
    int send_result = 0;

    // Set up the file descriptor set.
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);

    // Set up the timeval struct for the timeout.
    // We'll wait for 60 seconds for someone to connect and if someone doesn't connect, we'll cancel the server.
    server_wait_timeout.tv_sec = 60; // seconds
    server_wait_timeout.tv_usec = 0; // microseconds

    // Wait until the timeout or until we receive data.
    result = select(sock, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &server_wait_timeout);
    if (result == 0) {
        std::cout << "Timeout." << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if (result == -1)
        std::cerr << "Error occured while awaiting first connection data from client. Last WSA error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";

    receive_result = recvfrom(sock, receive_buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, &connection_data_len); // We set the first connected client as the only suitable connector from now on here.
    if (receive_result > 0) { // If we received any data before the timeout, let the client know that we acknowledge their request and return true.
        std::string ack_message = "ACK";

        send_result = sendto(sock, ack_message.c_str(), ack_message.length(), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, connection_data_len); // Let the client know that we received their message.
        if (send_result != SOCKET_ERROR)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::string ConnectionManager::receive_data() {
    ZeroMemory(receive_buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH); // Clean the receive buffer of any possibly remaining data.

    int receive_result = 42;
    u_long ioctl_result = 123;

    while (true) { // When ioctl with FIONREAD results 0, that means there's no datagram pending in the receive queue. We'll use this to grab only the last received package.
        receive_result = recvfrom(sock, receive_buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, &connection_data_len);

        ioctlsocket(sock, FIONREAD, &ioctl_result);
        if (ioctl_result == 0)
            break;
    }

    // Handle errors.
    if (receive_result > 0) {
        return std::string(receive_buffer, receive_result); // Using the built-in method of casting char to std::string.
    }
    else if (receive_result == 0)
        return "RECEIVEDNOTHING";
    else if (receive_result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        switch (WSAGetLastError()) {
            case WSAEWOULDBLOCK:
                return "WOULDBLOCK";
                break;
            case WSAECONNRESET:
                return "CONNRESET";
                break;
            case NTE_OP_OK:
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << "Unhandled error while receiving data: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        }
    return "NONE";
}
    
std::string ConnectionManager::send_data(std::string data) {
    int send_result = 666;
    send_result = sendto(sock, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&connection_data, connection_data_len);

    // Handle errors.
    if (send_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Error while sending data: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        return std::string("FAIL");
    }
    else
        return std::string("OK");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "connectionmanager.hpp"

int main() {
    ConnectionManager connection_manager;
    std::string connection_type;

    std::cout << "server or client?" << "\n";
    std::cin >> connection_type;

    if (connection_type == "client") {
        std::wstring ipv4_addr;

        std::cout << "ip address?" << "\n";
        std::wcin >> ipv4_addr;
        connection_manager.server_ipv4 = ipv4_addr;
    }


    connection_manager.type = connection_type;
    connection_manager.init(); // this works fine

    connection_manager.reset();

    connection_manager.init(); // client returns wsaerror 10054, server receives no data
}
```

Comment: Is this all code included really related to your question? Consider using [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "*I need to close and then reuse the same socket in my app*" - You can't reuse a closed `SOCKET` handle, unless you use Winsock's extended [`DisconnectEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms737757(v=vs.85)) function with the `TF_REUSE_SOCKET` flag, then the `SOCKET` can be reused with the [`AcceptEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex)/[`ConnectEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_connectex) function.  If you use `closesocket()`, you must create a new `SOCKET`

Comment: Also, your use of `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` is wrong. Those need to be moved into your `main()` instead.  Or, at the very least, `WSACleanup()` moved out of `ConnectionManager::init()` and into the `~ConnectionManager()` destructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I thought that since `ConnectionManager::Init()" reinitializes the socket, that would make it usable again.

Comment: @emredesu `init()` is creating a new socket object and assigning it to the `sock` member. That is reusing a variable, not reusing a socket object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by moving the sin_family and sin_port initialization to ConnectionManager::init() from the constructor and by editing the ConnectionManager::reset() to look like this:

```
void ConnectionManager::reset() {
    puts("reset!");
    is_connected = false;
    closesocket(sock);
    sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    memset(&connection_data, 0, sizeof(connection_data)); // Get rid of the data from the previous connection.
    memset(&receive_buffer, 0, sizeof(receive_buffer));
}
```